# Check,reset buttons active after all inputs were completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i make check and reset buttons active after 6 inputs were completed? I have tryed:

```
if($('.input') == ""){  
    checkBtn.disabled = true;
    resetBtn.disabled = true;
    }
else{
    checkBtn.disabled = false;
    resetBtn.disabled = false;
}
```

EDIT 2 with fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/usPMd/88/

Comment: Can you pls post relavant markup and NOT the entire web page?

Comment: gonna edit fiddle and post it as soon as possible

Comment: And just to clarify, you would like to enable those 2 buttons only when all 6 inputs have some value in them?

Comment: Yeap,on initial screen these buttons are inactive ,and when all 6 inputs are completed with correct or wrong answers i need em to activate.

Comment: OK, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** : Your Jsfiddle return error 404... So I developed a basic example (it is not perfect).

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3tep/sDY8c/)

Javascript solution :

```
<body>

    <form>
      <input type="text" onChange="checkInput()" onKeyup="checkInput()"/>
      <input type="text" onChange="checkInput()" onKeyup="checkInput()"/>
      <input type="text" onChange="checkInput()" onKeyup="checkInput()"/>
      <input type="text" onChange="checkInput()" onKeyup="checkInput()"/>
      <input type="text" onChange="checkInput()" onKeyup="checkInput()"/>
      <input type="text" onChange="checkInput()" onKeyup="checkInput()"/>
      <input id="send" type="submit" disabled/>
      <input id="reset" type="reset" disabled/>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var checkBtn = document.getElementById("send");
    var resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
    var inputTag, lengthInputTag, nbCompleted;

    function forEach( a, fn ) {
        return [].forEach.call(a, fn);
    };

    function checkInput(){
        inputTag = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        lengthInputTag = inputTag.length;
        nbCompleted = 0;
        console.log(inputTag);

        forEach(inputTag, function(el) {
           if(el.value != ""){
              nbCompleted++;
           }
        });

        if(nbCompleted < 6){
           checkBtn.disabled = true;
           resetBtn.disabled = true;
        }else{
           checkBtn.disabled = false;
           resetBtn.disabled = false;
        }  
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes your implementation is not good, I'll watch it again later

Comment: I change it abit and now its what i was looking for.Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
   if($('.input').length == 6){  
      checkBtn.disabled = false;
      resetBtn.disabled = false;
    }else{
      checkBtn.disabled = true;
      resetBtn.disabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So, use length then:

```
if($('.input').length == 7){ //after 6 is 7th input 
    checkBtn.disabled = true;
    resetBtn.disabled = true;
    }
```

And also there might be a typo `.input` should be `input` but not 100% sure because this might also be class.

Comment: it doesnt help :( on a function which load when doc ready i have checkBtn.disabled = true; and resetBtn.disabled = true; . I have changed ur code with false when input reach 5 to enable these buttons but doesnt work :(

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Here you go:

**Workign demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usPMd/91/)**

HTML (partial):

```
<button id="validateButton" class="validateButton" type="button" disabled="disabled">Check</button>
<button id="resetButton" class="resetButton" type="button" disabled="disabled">Reset</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('change blur', '.input', function(){
    var count = 0;
    $('.input').each(function(){
        var elem_v = $.trim ( $(this).val() );
        if (elem_v != "") {
            count++;
        }
    })
    $('button').prop('disabled', true);
    if (count===6){
        $('button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx for ur time,but on my project doesnt work :( i saw on fiddle is working...dunno whats going wrong :|

Comment: Well, this one precisely answers your "question" and hence qualifies as an answer. If you have other problems, you should post seperate questions.

Comment: Yes its a great answer,but dunno why it doesnt work on my project :(